# iOS mobile SDK 6.4.1 crashing (application protected data)

Tags: mobilepush, ios, mobilepush-ios

Our app is crashing after latest SDK update (v6.4.1). Push notification setup was updated using latest learning app example and docs related with application protected data.

Related code:

```
func applicationProtectedDataDidBecomeAvailable(_ application: UIApplication) {

    if !MarketingCloudSDK.sharedInstance().sfmc_isReady() {

        let config = CurrentConfig.config().pushConfig

        let builder = MarketingCloudSDKConfigBuilder()
            .sfmc_setApplicationId(config.appId)
            .sfmc_setAccessToken(config.accessToken)
            .sfmc_setMarketingCloudServerUrl(config.appEndpoint)
            .sfmc_setMid(config.mid)
            .sfmc_setInboxEnabled(true as NSNumber)
            .sfmc_setPiAnalyticsEnabled(true as NSNumber)
            .sfmc_setLocationEnabled(true as NSNumber)
            .sfmc_setAnalyticsEnabled(true as NSNumber)
            .sfmc_build()!

        do {
            try MarketingCloudSDK.sharedInstance().sfmc_configure(with: builder)
        } catch {
            reportError(error)
        }
    }

    // ...
}
```

Crash reports:

[image]
[image]

Comment: Can you provide details of the error from your reportError function in your catch handler?

Comment: I can't catch this crash directly, there just crashlytics info and I already provided. The strange thing is that this crash has only occurred in one version of app, and i can't see it on latest release (3 days live). Maybe it was just an SDK related backend error for some moment? I will keep my eyes on that for next several days and may close this issue.